# How to programically detect if display is plugged in to GPIO

Tags: gpio, display, python-3, raspberry-pi-os

I've attached an ePaper display to a GPIO bonnet/HAT and have set up `cron` jobs to run scripts that print data onto ePaper display.

If I remove the HAT and display, then how to check if it's plugged in?

If it is not plugged in, don't run the cronjobs.

Parts used:

- Adafruit Cyberdeck Bonnett
- Waveshare ePaper 2.13 inch Black/White
  display
- Raspberry Pi 400

The project details are here - [I wrote extensive readme:](https://github.com/omgitskuei/RPiDev/tree/main/RPi400/Cyberdeck_Stats_Monitor)

Or, leave the `cron` jobs alone and add an if statement in the main script cyberdeck_stats_monitor.py. If the display is not plugged in, the main script just does nothing.

Any other suggestions welcome.

Comment: Please add supporting information like; What type of eInk, How is it interfaced ++!

Comment: @Mastk Added name of parts used in the project. Can you explain what you mean by "how"? The ePaper's manual has a python library attached. The manual is linked in the repository and the library is in the repository's .../Cyberdeck_Stats_Monitor/library directory.

Comment: What interface is the eInk display using to connect to Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @Mastk The display is attached to a PCB called 2.13 inch ePaper HAT - It uses GPIO.

Comment: You appear to be the author of the linked code and are asking us to tell you how to use it? Is this just an attempt to get publicity? Either way YOU need to include in your Question details of interface - it is extremely unlikely anyone else has used it.

Comment: @Kuei Please read 2.13inch_e-Paper_V3_Specificition.pdf before answering about interfaces, GPIO is Generall Purpose I/O and can be configured for diccerent interface types.

Comment: @MatsK Thanks for the replies, I'm new to all this so I honestly didn't know what you meant. I googled your question verbatim but results didn't really explain that I can configure to read a ground pin in the gpio, and if ground changes to high then it is not plugged in. I apologize about misspelling your name - I'm a little dyslexic, I don't mean disrespect.

Comment: @Milliways I'm not sponsored in any way, and am not doing this for publicity. This is purely for learning and I just want to support the raspberry ecosystem because I like what it represents. I'm still very new and didn't totally understand everything in the vendor specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR :**  You've accumulated several negative comments to your question, and I mostly agree with them. But giving you [*the benefit of the doubt*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/benefit+of+the+doubt), I'll offer this as an answer:

This could be a straightforward, and easily-answered question except you've failed to share any details required to answer your question; let me explain:

1. One ***obvious*** way to do this is set up a GPIO pin as input, and pull it low when the board is *"plugged in"*. Your code can read the state of that GPIO pin, and know whether or not the device is *"plugged in"*. That's easy!
2. The problem with your question is that you provide **zero detail** on the electrical interface for this device. Without that information, we have no way to provide an answer that **shows how to translate *"plugged in"* to *"pull down a GPIO"***.
3. If you don't have the details of the device's electrical interface, that's unfortunate. You should learn a lesson, and stop buying from vendors who don't provide these details.
4. You should also briefly consider how you come across to the people here. You ask for help - an answer - but you've not invested enough time or effort to provide the details needed. Do you imagine that there are people willing to invest their time & effort to spoon-feed those who ask questions without investing their own time & effort? There's a section here called ["How to ask a good question"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask); perhaps you should read that?

Once you've done your homework, and shared the device data with us, ***one possible answer*** to your question may fall out as shown in the schematic below. In other words:

##### When your device is *"plugged in"*, there may be some connection point on your device that will allow current to flow through R1 to Ground (GND), and this current flow will "pull down" the GPIO input from 3.3V to GND. You can test the GPIO input in your code: if it is LOW (~0 V), your device is *"plugged in"*; if it is HIGH (~3.3V) your device is *"not plugged in"*

Note that R1 may be replaced with an *internal pullup* resistor. Here's an [article](https://grantwinney.com/using-pullup-and-pulldown-resistors-on-the-raspberry-pi/) that may explain how that's done in software.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnp42Y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! I needed to go back and read more about GPIO. Specifically, Setting a specific pin of the GPIO to "input" then reading whether it is high or low to determine if the circuit is closed.

Comment: @Kuei: That's a great idea! There should be plenty of examples available, and you'll maximize your learning experience with the "hands-on" effort.

Answer (score 1):

After reading more about GPIO and how specific pins can be set to "input" via Python GPIO module, I went back to the specifications of the ePaper display provided by the vendor, and looked to see which GPIO pin is used as GRD/ground for the display.
Under Chapter 5. Input/output Pin Assignment, ground is pin 17.
Following the example in [link] https://grantwinney.com/using-pullup-and-pulldown-resistors-on-the-raspberry-pi/#fixing-the-simple-circuit recommended by Seamus,

```
# coding=utf-8
 
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
 
def my_callback(channel):
    if GPIO.input(channel) == GPIO.HIGH:
        # display is not plugged in
    else:
        # display is plugged in
 
try:
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)  # Use board numbering of pins instead of BCM, which changes between Pi1 Model B
    GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.LOW, callback=my_callback)

   
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

I am in no way affiliated with any vendor/platform/etc, nor is this for profit in any way.

Comment: Glad to see you got this working :)